# how to redirect "www.somedomain.com/folder1/demo.jpg" request to some other page using mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

code block:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite.000webhostapp.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !folder1
RewriteRule ^(.jpg)$ http://mysite.00xxxtapp.com/folder1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your filename in the new url as well? (not just ".jpg")

`RewriteRule ([^/]+\.jpg)$ http://mysite.00xxxtapp.com/folder1/$1 [R=301,L]`

or 
`RewriteRule ([^/]+\.jpg)$ /folder1/$1 [L]`

if you want to keep seeing the old url

**EDIT**

So you need more than 1 rewriterule.

I suggest the steps

1. all "fake" urls redirect to some php script
2. all images in /folder1/ must be redirected or be made inaccessable (suggestion: put them outside the document root|)

`RewriteEngine On
    # all images in somefolder will be parsed through a php script
    RewriteRule somefolder/([^/]+\.jpg)$ /imageshower.php [L]`


    `# redirect to a no access image`

`RewriteRule folder/*\.jpg /no-access.jpg [R]`

The php script will be able to do some checking like 'is the user logged in?' or does he have the rights

```
<?php
  $filename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // this still points to the jpg
  if(is_file('folder/'. $filename) &&  is_allowed($user, $filename)) {

    header('Content-Type: images/jpg'); // or other like .gif or .pdf etc
    readfile('folder/'. $filename);
  }
?>
```

Comment: i am trying to protect my images files.If a user tries to access the image by directly writing the url(www.xyz.com/abc/image.jpg) in the address bar of browser i need to redirect him to some other page.

Comment: added some more to answer